# This simple vowel counter doesn't work

Tags: python

```
def counter(sentence):
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0
for char in sentence:
    if char == 'a' or 'A':
        a += 1
    elif char == 'e' or 'E':
        e += 1
    elif char == 'i' or 'I':
        i += 1
    elif char == 'o' or 'O':
        o += 1
    elif char == 'u' or 'U':
        u += 1
return a, e, i, o, u
```

Everything looks okay to me, but when I `print counter("Hello how is your day going")` it returns `(27, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. 27 is the total number of characters in that sentence so it's clear that for *every* character the for loop goes over, it stops after the first `if` condition and adds 1 to `a`, but I don't know why.

Also, messed up the indentation after the function definition, don't know how to fix it, obviously it's not like that in the program.

Answer (score 2):

When the if statement is evaluated, it evaluates as being `char == 'a'` and `'A'`. Since `'A'` is a boolean `True`, the `or` operator is triggered, and the `if` statement happens. Essentially, the `if` statement is translated as this:

```
(char == 'a') or 'A'
```

Demonstration

```
>>> char == 'a'
False
>>> 'A'
True
>>> True or False
True
```

Comment: Ah, okay, I see. The Python interpreter was reading it as `if (char == 'a') or 'A'`, and a string always evaluates to true. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little hint!

```
if char == "a" or char == "A":
    a += 1
```

etc.

Comment: is better `if char in "aA":` or `if char  in {"A", "a"}:`

Comment: I am looking for  the simplest extension possible that is consistent with the OP's attempt. This does not really lay open the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it:

```
v = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u',]
s = list("Hello World")
x = [i for i in v if i in s]
print x
```